# Could Detoxifying Foot Pads help someone pass a drug test?

Tags: natural-remedies, recreational-drugs

I just came across the phenomenon of 'Detoxifying Foot Pads'. They are supposed to draw toxins out of your feet by contact overnight or through the day.

It is claimed that [they help you pass a drug test](http://simplecannabis.com/drug-testing/natural-ways-to-pass-a-marijuana-drug-test/).

> **Detox Foot Pads will help you pass a marijuana drug test**
>
> In order to remove heavy metals, toxins, metabolic wastes, mucous, chemicals, microscopic parasites, cellulite and drug metabolites from prescription medicines these foot pads are very useful.

Is there evidence that footpads can improve your chances of passing a drug test?

Comment: Look at this: http://content.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,1877382,00.html

Comment: "@HappySpoon", "HostileFork" and now "Spork". We have our fair share of utensil-themed user names with monochrome avatars.

Comment: Also http://www.sciencebasedmedicine.org/the-detox-scam-how-to-spot-it-and-how-to-avoid-it/

Comment: @Oddthinking are you skeptical as to whether I am a seperate person? This sub-site is more paranoid than I thought! :)

Comment: @Cornelius there's a subscribe-wall in front of that link

Answer (score 4):

There is no way these things could work. Even if you could pull molecules through the skin, the skin on your feet would be the worst place to do it because it's the thickest. This would make more sense on the armpits, but still wouldn't be very effective. The major means of excreting substances from the body are through the urine or through the feces. This may require conjugating the molecule to make it more water soluble, or passing it into the bile, which gets dumped into the intestines and eventually becomes included in feces.

References: Detox footpads are BS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detoxification_foot_pads

Excretion pathways: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADME#Excretion

And if you don't trust wikipedia you can read what they cite. I have had 2 graduate courses in metabolism and toxicity of drugs and other molecules. Doesn't make me an expert, but enough to know detox footpads are crap.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1505)! Please [provide some references](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to support your claims.